# Multi thread problem with loop on ESP8266

Tags: if-statement, iot, esp8266, nodemcu

I'm using Nodemcu for my IoT project and I should use PHP with that. I'm trying to changing funcs, when I press the button on web site. My func1 has 1000ms delay with millis. func2 has a 360000ms delay, so I can't change func2 to func1 when I want to. I tried so many ways, how can I do that?

My code is like this:

```cpp
void func1() {
  // code for manuel GPIO control 
  // millis....
}

void func2() {
  // code for automatic GPIO control 
  // millis....
}

void loop() {
  // millis....
  if (payload == 1) {
    func1();
  } else if (payload == 0) {
    func2();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arduino does not support multi-threading, but you can use different programming technique to make your program to work without blocking, for example [Blink Without Delay](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/BlinkWithoutDelay)

Comment: Thank you for answering. I used Millis for that but my problem is different